# CS Cart Length/Volume price variables

Tags: ecommerce

I've just started using CS Cart and I'm wondering if it is possible to change a price on a variable such as length?

For example we have a cable which is 1-9999m, this is priced per unit, is it possible to set up a variable to times the number of units by the cost?

I realise this could be set up under a configurable product but I don't want to set up 10,000 individual products to reflect the length of cable

Comment: Message me on cs-cart's forums user panag for help with cs-cart

Comment: Trying to register on the forums and getting the following message when I try to submit my application - `The following errors were found: cant connect`

Comment: I'm on there now, not sure what the issue is let me know if you get registered

Comment: Still can't register, I fill out the form and hit submit and it throws that error back at me!

Comment: Just contacted you through your site

Comment: Dropped you a couple of emails Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a product with a starting price of 1m then they can select a length by the Quantity input and the price can adjust that way. You can also set the product price to $0 and force a minimum order qty of 1m.

Another option is to price it in blocks of 5 or 10 meters. Set options for the product so you're only creating say 100 options and you'll only have to set the price in 100 options generated.